# finding optimal weight using Kelly criterion

Tags: log-returns, utility-theory, kelly-criterion

Question: Suppose you have two strategies.  Strategy 1 gains 8% with probability p, and loses 5% with probability 1-p, where p = 0.53.  Strategy 2 gains 8% with probability q, and loses 5% with probability 1-q, where q = 0.51.  The outcomes of the two strategies are independent.  You assign weights (which sum to one) for the two strategies.  What will the optimal weight be for Strategy 1 (to nearest 0.001), if you goal is to maximize your expected growth rate (i.e. maximize log utility, i.e. the Kelly criterion)?

Answer: 0.813

What I have tried: using log utility function I tried to set up an equation for both strategies and maximize the alpha. But clearly, my equation is wrong. Please help!

Comment: It would be better to assign a probability *distribution* to each strategy rather than assign binary probability outcomes to each

Comment: Hi @develarist, can you elaborate on this in relation to the question on the Kelly criterion? Thanks!

Comment: @develarist - AFAIK, Kelly is for sizing bets with binary outcomes. Do you have a link that discusses extensions to continuous (or multiple discrete) outcomes? Thanks!

Comment: don't you think any model based on binary outcomes is unrealistic

Comment: "don't you think any model based on binary outcomes is unrealistic" - in general, yes, though in fairness it depends on the bets you're making (e.g. you could trade nothing but digitals and then your outcome is binary!).